# How recreate only selected spring context in spring tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, integration-testing, spring-test

The typical exmaple is:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:someITTest-mock.xml",
        "classpath:someITTest-context.xml",
        "classpath:commons.xml"})
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SomeITTest {
//...
}
```

I am finding the way to recreate mocks during tests. The obvious way to use [DirtiesContext](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)
But it results to recreate all contexts, when only mock context should be recreated.

Here is several notes:

1. Context with mock seems to be loaded first, because other depended
   context do not have such beans.
2. When mocks are created and injected
   into depended context, it is probably impossible to cache/reuse
   depended context.

So is there a way to recreate spring context where mocks are created, but leave other context cached?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** If you are using Spring Boot 1.4, you can use its first-class support for mocking beans via `@MockBean`.

> So is there a way to recreate spring context where mocks are created, but leave other context cached?

No, that is not possible.

In your example, there is in fact only *one* single `ApplicationContext` which is loaded from all three XML configuration files. If you create a hierarchy using `@ContextHierarchy`, there would be multiple contexts; however, it is impossible to reload only a parent context (see other comments I've posted in this thread).

However, one common approach that people take in such scenarios is to explicitly *reset* the mocks in question.

There are basically two ways to achieve this.

1. If the mocks are injected into the integration test (e.g., via `@Autowired`) you can simply *reset* the mocks in an *after* method (e.g., in an `@After` method in JUnit 4).
2. Otherwise, you can implement and register a custom `TestExecutionListener` that retrieves the mocked beans from the `ApplicationContext` and resets them (e.g., in the `afterTestMethod()` method).

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `@ContextHierarchy` and `@DirtiesContext`:

```
@ContextHierarchy({
@ContextConfiguration(name="parent",
    locations = {"classpath:someITTest-context.xml", "classpath:commons.xml"}),
@ContextConfiguration(name="child",
    locations = "classpath:someITTest-mock.xml")
})
@DirtiesContext(hierarchyMode = CURRENT_LEVEL)
```

With this, only the *child* context should be reloaded, see [Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-framework).

Comment: Although you are correct about only the child context being reloaded in your example, this will likely not solve the original problem.

Comment: I assume that `commons.xml` relies on beans declared in `someITTest-mock.xml`. Thus, mocked beans declared in the latter must be visible to beans declared the former. With the parent-child hierarchy you have proposed, this would be impossible. A parent context cannot see beans defined in a child context.